# JSP - How do I print out empty <td> when values are duplicated?

Tags: java, jsp, duplicates, jstl, el

Below I have JSP code that prints out the first picture. I am trying to achieve what is in the second picture.

I have 8 columns total. The first 4 columns print out as long as there is data from an inner joined table which includes the last 4 columns where the data will vary. I'm looking to print out empty data or space in the columns and rows where information is duplicated from above. There can be up to 6 rows for each ID (far left column).

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
  <th>Student ID</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Grade</th>
  <th>Events</th> 
  <th>Participation Level</th>
  <th>Ind/Team</th> 
  <th>Event Name</th>       
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">


  <% theStudentId = 123 ; %>
  <% System.out.println("at " + (new java.util.Date()) + ", theStudentId is " + theStudentId); %>

  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${row.idStudents}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.LastName}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.FirstName}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.Grade}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.idEvents}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.Grade}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.Type}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.Name}"/></td>
  </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

This is what the jsp prints out as of now.

[image: current]

This is what I wish to achieve.

[image: target]

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the last value.   Just before this part:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
```

You should create a variable called `lastStudentId` (initially null).

Inside of the loop, check to see if the current student ID is equal to the lastStudentId.  (I can't tell how to do this because you haven't provided type information for those fields, I assume they're strings).  If it's the same as the last one, print empty td's (e.g. containing an &nbsp;).   If it's not the same, then do what you normally do.

At the bottom of the loop, assign `lastStudentId = row.idStudents` and you're good to go.